# how to remove fragments history after closing the app or after locale change

Tags: android, android-fragments, locale

Whenever I chagne language from settings, and restart my app immediately, all the layouts ( instance variables) are reset to null but the fragment still exists when i try to access by getFRagmentByTag.
So, I end up getting null pointer exceptions

I want to remove all the information of fragments in my app when the app is closed ( on press of home or recent or back button).

Is it possible to remove all the history of fragments.
Did anyone face similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentMan.popBackStack();
```

Pop-ing back the stack clears with the back stack with one element. Consider pop-ing back more times to match your number of elements in the stack or even make e for loop to call popBackStack many times to clear all the fragments.